# Free or open-source lightweight Install Monitor

Tags: windows, monitoring, installer

Dear Software Recommendation Community,

Could you please advise on a name of free or open-source lightweight **tool for tracing every single CHANGE** of Windows file-system and registry (meaning, to capture CHANGEs before and after Installation, not the complete system snapshot) **of an executable file** and its dependentants (**during Installation**), in real-time, writing detailed information to its own log, **obviously using the kernel mode driver**?

Windows Step Recorder and real-time process/thread activity with
Sysinternal Process Monitor (Filemon+Regmon) does not suit my needs.

I don't really need UnInstalling (paid) feature usually bundled witch such tools, eg. Mirekusoft or Crystalidea apps.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome!

> Hints: Install Tracker; Install Monitor, Install Logger

Comment: If you write that something doesn't meet your expectations, write **why**. Process Monitor would be my 1st recommendation as it does the job very well with proper filtering.

Comment: You are right! procmon64.exe indeed does offer  **(start/stop of) advanced and boot event logging**, every 0.1+ seconds, **generated into its own native processes monitor format .pml**, but also into xml and csv. - ie. thread profiling, for later threat profiling.